# Can't call child window functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have this Vue page which opens a child window one using following line;

```
this.presentation = window.open(
    this.$router.resolve({name:'presentation'}).href,
    'child window',
    'width=auto,height=auto'
);
```

This works like a charm, but now I need to call it's methods.
I tried to accessing them like so.
Parent:

```
this.presentation.setPage(0);
```

Child:

```
export default {
  name: 'Presentation',
  data() {
    return {
      page: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setPage(_page) {
      this.page = _page;
    }
  }
```

This throws following error.

```
TypeError: "this.presentation.setPage is not a function"
```

Why can't I call child methods? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from the [`window.open()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> **windowName**
>
> ... The name should not contain whitespace. ...
>
> **Return value:**
>
> A Window object representing to the newly created window.

Your `this.presentation` contains `Window` object, *not* the `Vue` object. Of course, it doesn't have `setPage()` method.

Perhaps, something like that could work (in your child component):

```js
{
  mounted() {
    window.setPage = (page) => this.setPage(page);
  }
}
```